# How to insert algorithm as text using listings package

Tags: pdftex, listings

Good afternoon ,

I need to write some algorithm steps as text using listings package :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 right=10mm,
 left=10mm
 }

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{
language=C++,
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
numbersep=5pt,
xleftmargin=20pt,
frame=tb,
framexleftmargin=20pt
}



\DeclareCaptionFormat{mylst}{\hrule#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=mylst,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=off,labelsep=space}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}

\title{Mouad PHD }
\author{Mouad TOUARSI}
\date{ }

% THEOREMS -------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Summary}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents{}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={},caption={test algorithm}]

\text{Initialiser} : sélectionnez aléatoirement k des n points de données comme médoïdes \\

    \textbf{Étape d’assignation :} associez chaque point de données au médoïde le plus proche (En utilisant par exemple la distance L2). \\

    \textbf{Étape de mise à jour} : Pour chaque médoïde m et chaque point de données o associé à m permutez m et o et calculez le coût total de la configuration (c'est-à-dire la dissimilarité moyenne de o avec tous les points de données associés à m ). Sélectionnez le médoïde o avec le coût le plus bas de la configuration. \\

    \textbf{Répétez les étapes 2 et 3} en alternance jusqu'à ce qu'il n'y ait aucun changement dans les affectations. \\

\end{lstlisting}



\end{document}
```

Using this approach , the printed result looks bad !

I only need to see the steps written as the standard text ( but within the algorithm )

[image]
Thank you for help !

Comment: Could someone give a suggestion

Comment: This looks like a lesson for NSI in french high school. Am I right?

Comment: @projetmbc , i got this from wikipedia and other sources LIKE : https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-01252973v3/file/classif-cours.pdf . I'm just in the begining of writing my thesis report !

Comment: I don't know what the term NSI  means but i'm working in ML

Comment: I said that because this is an example of algorithm teached in "Terminale Spécialité Numérique et Science de l'Informatique".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve this problem is using xelatex.

I deleted \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and changed the engine to xelatex,
then I got an output that seems good.

Comment: Yes , thank you a lot !

Answer (score 2):

I think you're better off using a regular `algorithm` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Test algorithm}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Initialiser :} sélectionnez aléatoirement k des n points de données comme médoïdes
    \item \textbf{Étape d’assignation :} associez chaque point de données au médoïde le plus proche (En utilisant par exemple la distance L2).
    \item \textbf{Étape de mise à jour} : Pour chaque médoïde m et chaque point de données o associé à m permutez m et o et calculez le coût total de la configuration (c'est-à-dire la dissimilarité moyenne de o avec tous les points de données associés à m ). Sélectionnez le médoïde o avec le coût le plus bas de la configuration.
    \item \textbf{Répétez les étapes 2 et 3} en alternance jusqu'à ce qu'il n'y ait aucun changement dans les affectations.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes , but i avoided {algorithm} package because it's difficult to split it across multiple pages

Comment: @TouMou: True; floats are blocks that can't be broken (without some work). It's possible to have continued algorithms that span multiple pages though.

Comment: @TouMou: What do your other algorithms look like? Different code, or all just text-based?

Comment: For this case it's ok but i hope of there is a way to split algorithm even manually . Some of algorithms contains mixture of equations and text

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85390/divide-an-algorithm-on-two-pages

Comment: @TouMou: Many things are possible. You can set a manual caption that would represent the start of the algorithm, followed by whatever you want (like an enumerated list, broken with equations in between) and then close it off with a horizontal rule to signify the end of the algorithm. This would allow it to break across numerous pages.

Comment: thank you a lot for your precious help !